# Neo4j/Cypher - combing two queries - tree hierarchy with count()

Tags: neo4j, cypher

We have a tree structure where a parent node can have zero or more children, and a child node has one parent (except at the root). We are working with two queries, the first with single digit millisecond response, and the second with three digit millisecond response. I have been trying to combine them into one, but the response time increases to 10, 20 or 30 seconds. Maybe it can't be done?

```
// return all the children immediately under the Set in the right order
match (parent:Set{uuid:{parentuuid}}) 
match (firstChild:Set)-[:FirstChildOf]->(parent) 
match (sibling:Set)-[:Sibling*]->(firstChild) 
return firstChild + collect(sibling) as nodes

// for each child in previous query, return count of functional locations
match (node:Set{uuid:{uuid}})<-[:ChildOf*]-(f:FunctionalLocation) 
return count(f)
```

Comment: Show your combined query in your question.

Comment: `match (parent:Set{uuid:{parentuuid}})<-[:FirstChildOf]-(firstChild:Set) 

with collect(firstChild.uuid) as children,parent

match (parent)<-[:ChildOf*]-(f:FunctionalLocation) return children,count(f)`. You can't return nodes and values at once using one query. Can you try and tell the exec time for this one?

Comment: 68ms for that query. It returns the first child (with count), but is missing the other children (and their counts).